# mysqli_stmt::execute(): Premature EOF in result field metadata

Tags: php, mysqli

I am writing a PHP application using MySQLi. During the run of this application, I prepare many SQL prepared statements in succession, and then execute them as needed throughout the course of the application.

However, when I run the same specific statement twice within my application (with specific parameters), I get the following error: `mysqli_stmt::execute(): Premature EOF in result field metadata`.

To further clarify my problem, I attach a minimal reproducible example of my code. Firstly, my database contains a stored procedure called `GET_USER_ID_FROM_USERNAME`. This is exactly as the name suggests - it takes a string username as parameter, checks if the username exists, and then returns two values - a boolean labelled `User_Exists` to check if the username is known in the database, and (if the former is `true`) an integer labelled `ID`. Here is the code for this procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_USER_ID_FROM_USERNAME (IN Username_Param TINYTEXT CHARSET utf8mb4)
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Users WHERE Username = Username_Param) = 1) THEN
    SELECT ID, TRUE AS User_Exists FROM Users WHERE Username = Username_Param;
    ELSE
    SELECT FALSE AS User_Exists;
    END IF;
END
```

This works exactly how I want it to - when I pass in a known username, it returns `true` in the `User_Exists` column and the relevant user's `ID` in the eponymous column, and when I pass in a username not featuring in the database, it returns `false` in the `User_Exists` column.

The problem arises when I call this procedure *twice* (even if I call other procedures in between), and only **when the first time is an existing username and the second time is an unknown one** (i.e. when the `User_Exists` value is `true` the first time but `false` the second). I call this routine using a prepared statement, to which I bind the username desired.

Here is a minimal example of the code which throws the desired error:

```php
// CONNECT
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "test_database");
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli->autocommit(false);
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

// PREPARE STATEMENT
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("CALL GET_USER_ID_FROM_USERNAME (?);");

// BIND PARAMETER
$username = "";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

// EXECUTE WITH KNOWN VALUE
$username = "Existing_Username";
$stmt->execute();
// Flush result (if I exclude this I get a "commands out of sync" error)
$stmt->get_result();
$mysqli->next_result();

// All fine so far

// EXECUTE WITH UNKNOWN VALUE
$username = "Fake_Username";
$stmt->execute(); // <- Error thrown here: mysqli_stmt::execute(): Premature EOF in result field metadata
```

This (and only this) configuration, where the first username is known and the second is not, throws the error. If the statement is only called once, with either a known or unknown username, it returns what I expect. If the statement is called first with a known username and second with a different known username, it also returns what I expect.

Looking for the error message `Premature EOF in result field metadata` has yielded no results. If someone knows how or why this message appears, or has an idea of what I am doing wrong with my code, I'd be grateful to know!

This is the `Users` table as I have set it up for the purposes of this example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users (
  ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  Username TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
  Pass_Hash TINYTEXT NOT NULL
);
```

Rows:

```
ID   -   Username      -     Pass_Hash
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        Existing_Username   $2y$10$l8y.GEK3LFnLyJWhAmHdg.7lMb45SezorBDODrqWUq4M0K1P3rDCq
```

(the Pass_Hash is `Password1`, hashed).

The setup I am running this on:

MAMP on Windows

PHP 8.1.0

MySQL 5.7.24

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with PHP 8.2 and MariaDB 10.4

Comment: For questions like this it would be good if you could reproduce it on https://phpize.online/

Comment: The thing is "Premature EOF in result field metadata" is a mysqlnd error that should NEVER happen. It's super strange that you somehow managed to get this error. Especially since you are using not so old versions of PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Haven't been able to reproduce it on phpize.online - will continue trying, but of course this won't be much use if it is indeed a platform-specific problem. And very odd that you say it should never happen - has this not been encountered at all before?

Comment: I'd call MySQL 5.7 pretty old at this point... Anyway my first step would be to update PHP to latest 8.1. Maybe also see if it works without binding parameters. Just pass them as an array to execute method. Also you are calling a stored procedure; does the error happen with a normal statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in PHP and it was [fixed in PHP 8.1.23 & 8.2.10](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php#8.1.27)

Here is the PR https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/11551

I have verified that this is the same bug, despite the bug description being a little bit different.

---

As you can see the issue has been reported before although with different symptoms. I'd guess that not many people run into this problem because what you are doing is quite unusual. Stored procedures are not usually used from within PHP code and when they are they are usually executed only once. It's not unthought of to execute stored procedure multiple times using a prepared statement, but it's a rather rare circumstance.

Comment: Much obliged. Is it considered bad practice to run stored procedures in PHP using prepared statements? I'm currently doing this a lot in my application, and now worrying if it has any implications on speed / efficiency etc. I believed it was more secure (since all my actual SQL code is pre-written in the actual database), but I'm surprised to learn it's not common.

Comment: @brian I would not say it's bad practice. It's just really cumbersome with no benefits. Stored procedures should be used for complex operations performed by DBA directly on the server. Using SP in PHP doesn't make much sense. You can just perform the same queries straight from PHP. It doesn't improve security, and if you do it wrong, it can even worsen security. Complexity is the enemy of security. SPs also hide from the PHP developer the actual logic making it more difficult to write code around it in PHP.